# Build Ionic 3 Angular 4 app as webpage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Is it possible to build my Ionic 3 Angular 4 Android app as a webpage?

I have tried 'ionic Cordova build web' which results in lots of errors. Just wanted to make sure this is possible and the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you means ionic as **mobile web**, there are two simple way to use it.

Firstly, if you don't need browser dependent functions, just do `ionic build` with options you need.

and then, use **www** folder as your SPA website.

Secondly, if you need browser dependent functions which described in [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/), install some plugins you want and command `ionic cordova platform add browser` and build `ionic cordova build browser` with options you need.

and then, use **platforms/browser/www** folder as your SPA website.